# GEarthView plugin problem- QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, point, google-earth, qgis-2.12

I try to see a point layer that been created in QGIS 2.12 in Google Earth and the problem is that I can't see the point in there - it only located me in the right frame with out the point layer.

[image: lots of points]

[image: satellite image]

I tried to turn on all the layers but had no success:

[image: qgis menu]

Comment: Have you tried setting the **Control rendering order** in the _Layer Order Panel_?

Answer (score 1):

Is your point layer active in QGIS ?

GEarthView publishes vector data only of the active layer.

BTW, in your image I see that "Move QGIS" network link is red in GoogleEarth:  this means "error".